# Why does my actix Supervisor not retry stopped actors?

Tags: rust, rust-actix

I have implemented an [actix](https://actix.rs/) actor including the `Supervised` trait. I then tried to start the actor in a supervised way using

```
let _: Addr<Unsync, _> = Supervisor::start(|_| MyActor::default());
```

Unfortunately when that actor stops it is not automatically restarted for some reason.

---

#### Dependency Versions

```
actix = "0.5"
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nikolay Kim, the author of actix, helped me analyze the issue. It turns out that assigning the `Supervisor::start()` result to a variable called `_` will automatically throw away the result and so the supervisor will not actually start correctly.

The solution to this issue is renaming the `_` variable to `_addr`:

```
let _addr: Addr<Unsync, _> = Supervisor::start(|_| MyActor::default());
```

After the rename the `Supervisor` correctly restarts the `MyActor` actor after it has stopped.

Comment: don't make any sense.

Comment: This is part of a more generic aspect of binding a value to `_`: unlike in other languages, `_` is a special token, not a variable name. It is used explicitly not to bind the value to anything, so the given `Addr` is immediately dropped. Whether this would influence how actix works, that would depend on the crate's implementation details.